# Definition of Lebesgue integrable function

Tags: functions, lebesgue-integral

If a function $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to [-\infty,\infty]$ is Lebesgue integrable, then by definition we have $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x)| \, dx < +\infty.$$ Is it possible to say that there exists a nonnegative $g(x)$ such that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x)| \, dx \le \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g(x) \, dx < +\infty,$$
and so $|f(x)| < g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$?

The reason I ask is because I want to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem for another exercise I am working on.

Comment: that integral inequality doesn't guarantee $|f(x)|\le g(x)$, even if you assume $g\ge 0$. Perhaps you wanted to ask something slightly different?

Comment: @AdamHughes If that's the case, then what counterexample can we come up with? $f(x) = \frac 1x$?

Comment: That $f$ is not integrable, I'm not sure what you're asking for in that case.

Comment: In fact $g(x) = |f(x)|$ has your property (except for the strict inequality).

Comment: Then what hint can you give me that will allow me to prove the exercise: If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable, then $\int_{-N}^N f \to \int f$ as $N \to \infty$?

Comment: @dragon if $f$ is integrable, then you can use $|f|$ as the dominating function to prove $f\cdot 1_{[-N,N]}$ is an integrable sequence. That it converges to $\int f$ is readily seen since you know the tails of the integral go to $0$ by definition of integrability.

Comment: Hint to that is to consider functions $f\chi_{[-N,N]}=g_N$. Then $|g_N|\leq |f(x)|$ and the limit converges. Then dominated convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample: Let $c=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x)|dx$. Then $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x)|\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} c\chi_{I^d}dx<\infty$ but it is not true that $|f(x)|<c\chi_{I^d}$ for all $x$. Here $I^d=[0,1]^d$